# How to pass a business opportunity to a company and ask for money

Tags: websites, sales, business, referral

I had an interview for a company that does UX analytics for some major global brands. It went OK technically - I think I could do the job (3rd line/tech support for their JavaScript library) - but location is an issue and I didn't get on very well with the guy I spoke to (the CEO). So, via the recruiter, we agreed to leave it at that.

In the meantime, I was talking to a friend who is a Senior Front End Developer at a major UK bank about the library and what it does. He thought his team might be interested in using the analytics company's library. It could be a very useful tool for them.

So I could put the CEO of the analytics company in contact with the web team at the bank. Obviously this would be putting a potentially very lucrative business opportunity in front of the analytics company, so I would want some money for my involvement!

How could I go about asking the CEO of the analytics company for some money to refer them to the web team of the bank?

I didn't like the CEO very much so I have no qualms about wanting money from them - but I'm not sure how to pitch it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

Not gonna happen. Companies don't go around paying for unqualified leads - not individually, anyway. The administrative cost of sorting it out just makes it not worth it.

Your best bet would be to get your friend to buy you a couple of beers if he uses the library.

Comment: It would be the CEO that would owe me the beers for sending some business his way, but that's not gonna happen either... thanks though!